# Where to store application global variable?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I'm using silverlight, project structure is similiar to any other .net app. I have a map control that I would like to store what mode it is in (either road or aerial) so that other controls can access this.

Where do I put this enum variable, I plan to use 2 way binding on it so both are updated when either changes.

Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking about using a static class but I bet there is another 'official' way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a property to your data model, or to a Singleton pattern as suggested by Reed.
2. Follow the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(VS.95).aspx) pattern so that data binding will work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need to implement this as a property within a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), if you want to use data binding in a clean manner.

Jon Skeet has a [great post showing how to implement singletons in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this link about global.asax and the application object helpful:
http://odetocode.com/articles/89.aspx

"Which is better: storing object references in the Application object, or making static member variables and properties in the Global class..."